# How to merge results of two select statements into one table with two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two `SELECT` statements. Both give me the same amount of rows and the values relate to each other.

```
SELECT testtime
FROM testinspection
WHERE sample_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM sample
    WHERE name = '12_1')

SELECT image
FROM testedsampleimage
WHERE id in (
    SELECT testedsampleimage_id
    FROM testinspection
    WHERE sample_id = (
        SELECT id 
        FROM sample 
        WHERE name = '12_1'))
```

So in my example I have a test image for a specific test time and I want to have both results in one table, like this (for example):

```
TESTTIME | IMAGE
-------------------
15       | <LONG>
63       | <LONG>
78       | <LONG>
25       | <LONG>
12       | <LONG>
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.testtime,i.image
FROM sample s
   join testinspection t on t.sample_id = s.id
   join testedsampleimage i on t.testedsampleimage_id = i.id
WHERE s.name = '12_1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a 1-1 relation between the two tables based on `id`,  `testedsampleimage_id` fields. In this case you can use a simple `JOIN` operation:

```sql
SELECT testtime, image
FROM testinspection
JOIN testedsampleimage ON id = testedsampleimage_id
WHERE sample_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM sample
    WHERE name = '12_1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `union` for combining result of two select statement.

```
SELECT testtime
FROM testinspection
WHERE sample_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM sample
    WHERE name = '12_1')

UNION ALL    

SELECT image
FROM testedsampleimage
WHERE id in (
    SELECT testedsampleimage_id
    FROM testinspection
    WHERE sample_id = (
        SELECT id 
        FROM sample 
        WHERE name = '12_1'))
```

If you want to remove duplicate values then use only `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.